# Error deserializing JSON to a class with IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net

I need to return a collection with nested optional collections from my WebAPI and convert it back to objects in my Web UI, however I'm getting the following error:

Cannot create and populate list type System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MyNamespace.MyClass].

I'm using Json.Net.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
public class ClassA
{
  public Int64 Id { get; set; }

  public String Description { get; set; }

  public IEnumerable<ClassB> { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB
{
  public Int64 Id { get; set; }
  public String Description { get; set; }
}
```

I've saw some questions here in stackoverflow, but I don't have access to serialization options (it is handled internally by our library).

UPDATE

I've forgot to mention that ClassA is returned as an IQueryable in my Web API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the return type of my Web API method to IEnumerable instead of IQueryable solved the problem.